# Como iniciar o Serviço de Estado do ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu configurei o meu `Web.config` com a seguinte instrução:

```
<sessionState timeout="30" mode="StateServer" />
```

Porém quando rodo a aplicação (um site ASP.NET), recebo o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível fazer a solicitação de estado de sessão ao servidor de estado de sessão. Verifique se o serviço de estado do ASP.NET foi iniciado e se as portas do cliente e do servidor são a mesma.

Me lembro que tive que ativar esse serviço da última vez que ocorreu esse erro, mas não sei mas como se faz.

Como faço pra ativar esse serviço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução foi bem simples:

1 - Abra o `services.msc` através do comando "Executar" do Windows.

2 - Procure pelo serviço `Asp.NET State Service`

3 - Clique  em `Iniciar`.

4 - Se quiser que o mesmo seja executado automaticamente, clique duas vezes sobre o serviço e, na opção `Tipo de Inicialização`, escolha `Automático`.

Exemplo:

[image: Como iniciar o serviço de estado do ASP NET]